# How to insert data in sorted file in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to insert data in file in C++. I need to insert First and Last Name. All the lines in the file are sorted by the Last Name first, and then by the First Name. So my problem is when i insert new line how to insert on the right place and all the records still be sorted?

With this code i just append data in file, but don't know how to sort
`

```
string fName,lName;
cout<<"Insert Last Name: "<<endl;
    cin>>lName;

cout<<"Insert First Name: "<<endl;
cin>>fName;

ofstream myfile("sort.dat",ios::app);
myfile<<fName<<" "<<lName;`
```

Comment: This basically works out to: "how do I implement a database?"

Comment: Load everything into a data structure in RAM, do the insert, and then write it back. But I recommend using a database library or serialization library instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things working even with the code you posted:

1. You need to check if your input was successful before processing any input. Otherwise you could, e.g., end up with empty strings being inserted into your file, probably corrupting its content.
2. You almost certainly need to put a newline into the target file when appending the new content.

That is, your input could, for example, look like this:

```
std::string fName, lName;
if (std::cout << "Insert last name: "
    && std::cin >> lName
    && std::cout << "Insert first Name: "
    && std::cin >> fName) {
    // now do something with the read values
}
else {
    // deal with the error
}
```

The next step is "insert into a file": that doesn't work. Sorting a file is bound to work even less! Instead, what you would copy the file to a new destination and insert the record at the opportune location

1. Read each line of the existing file. If the record is smaller than the new record, write it and go to line 1.
2. Write new record.
3. Write the already read record.
4. Copy the remaining content of the original file.
5. Close both files.
6. Remove the original file and rename the new file to the name of the original file.

I could type out the code but I don't really need exercise with reading/writing files.